# Writing list of strings into Text file adding as attachment to the mail using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, c#-4.0

I am using below code to send an mail with the text file as a attachment and  the contents of text file like this **"License ADD LOGJz+RC-cVecSpK5-57AOrUlA-6aD3n5Fy-ejFGFIIa-XPU"**

```
    public static bool sendMailFromToCCSubMsgAttachment(string fromName, string fromAdd, string toline, string subj, string htmlmsg, string cc, string strAttachment)
    {

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MAIL_SERVER"], Int32.Parse(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SERVER_PORT"]));
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strAttachment))
        {
            ContentType ct = new ContentType();
            ct.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;

            Attachment attachFile = Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(strAttachment, ct);



            mail.Attachments.Add(attachFile);
        }
  .........
  .........
  ..........
   }
```

Here We are passing above content in **"strAttachment"** variable to this method
now i am looking to pass list of strings as contents to that text file and the content format like this below..

```
License ADD 2N674h5A-cVc9XiCG-N0TChPo3-mRVmOtUm-GYup9evK-3d4
License ADD VljH169B-cVe22hrW-U/HMICqW-1aeB5pJE-YpZIOThd-eBc
License ADD FIsc70dC-cVeVN9Ed-J833n4q4-vyMgnOXM-HjsMKrhT-qy0
License ADD LOGJz+RC-cVecSpK5-57AOrUlA-6aD3n5Fy-ejFGFIIa-XPU
```

How can i add these list of strings as contents to the text file using above code snippet ..
Would any one please help on this ..
Many thanks in advance....

Comment: is making a temp file with these strings in an option - that would be quick and simple, maybe otherwise a memory stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change input parameter to `List<string>` and inside method create a string variable to hold Those string separated by Newline, write these to your attachment file.

Like this

```
 public static bool sendMailFromToCCSubMsgAttachment(string fromName, string fromAdd, string toline, string subj, string htmlmsg, string cc, List<string> strAttachment)
        {

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MAIL_SERVER"], Int32.Parse(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SERVER_PORT"]));
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            string strAttachmentboyd = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, strAttachment);
            // your other code
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for attaching a file into an email.

```
public static void sendMailWithAttachment(string strAttachment)
{
//insert the licence into a memorystream.
//Note not using the 'using' statement with the MemoryStream and StreamWriter.
//If you do you will get a 'cannot access a closed stream' error when attaching the stream into the email
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(strAttachment);
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;

//start the mail sending
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
using (MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage())
{
    //mail config settings
    client.Port = 25;
    client.Host = "localhost";
    client.Timeout = 30000;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "passWord");

    //mail content stuff
    oMail.From = new MailAddress("fake@false.nl", "yourName");
    oMail.To.Add(new MailAddress("fake@false.nl"));
    oMail.Subject = "Your Licence";
    oMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    oMail.Body = "<html><head></head><body> Hello </body></html>";

    //insert the text file as attatchment from the stream
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strAttachment))
    {
        oMail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "Licence.txt", "text/plain"));
    }

    //send the mail
    client.Send(oMail);
}

//dispose the stream and writer containing the license
writer.Dispose();
stream.Dispose();
}
```